# Suggested benchmark for testing CPU footprint of antivirus software

Tags: performance, anti-virus, speed, benchmarking

Our organization is currently running Symantec Corporate Antivirus, which is rumored to be a big resource hog.  I know that we do have a lot of older machines that are running slow.  Our PCs are all running Windows XP Pro and are used only for business applications (mostly Microsoft Office), e-mail, and web surfing.  They're not used for gaming (one would hope not, anyway).

I'd like to take one of the old PCs and do a speed benchmark test while it's running Symantec AV, then another test with no antivirus, and a third test with ESET NOD32.  As I said, I don't care much about graphics performance.

What would be an appropriate benchmarking program program to use?  Freeware is best, of course.

Thank you for considering my question.

Comment: The /best/ tool is probably XPerf, but that's probably overkill for what you want. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found 4 free CPU benchmark utilities.  I haven't tried them though.

[PC Wizard 2010](http://download.cnet.com/PC-Wizard-2010/3000-2094_4-10793737.html) .

[NovaBench](http://novabench.com/).

[Fresh Diagnosis](http://www.freshdevices.com/freshdiag.html).

[CPU Speed Professional](http://downloads.zdnet.com/abstract.aspx?docid=1846757).