# Kaspersky is slowing my computer

Tags: installation, microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint, kaspersky

I installed windows 7 32bit on a dell inspiron laptop but when i installed kaspersky 2014 the laptop became very slow when opening microsoft 2007 word, excell,and powerpoint programs and even when i try to open documents.
please help me.

Comment: You might consider disabling file access scanning (if it has it). File access scanning monitors every time a programm accesses a file using up your system resources. Personally, if I know my system is clear to start with and emails and downloads are checked then I'm happy.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much you can do. Antivirus software is generally more harmful then viruses. It slows down your machine, consumes unreasonable amount of RAM and prevents programs from running normally. These are all the features, that modern antivirus can offer.

If the safety is very important to you, then you just have to learn to live with it.

You may find these threads interesting:

- [Installed new Antivirus Software now Computer is extremely slow! Can I fix that?](https://superuser.com/q/581793/281154)
- [Can computer be safe without antivirus?](https://superuser.com/questions/737745/can-computer-be-safe-without-antivirus)
- [What is the "lightest" -> not messing with system registry antivirus](https://superuser.com/questions/496622/what-is-the-lightest-not-messing-with-system-registry-antivirus)
- [Suggested benchmark for testing CPU footprint of antivirus software](https://superuser.com/questions/234436/suggested-benchmark-for-testing-cpu-footprint-of-antivirus-software)

Good luck and welcome to SU

Comment: +1 for saying it generally more harmful than viruses!  We'll take the rare virus we have to deal with over the EVERYDAY slowness.  We haven't ran antivirus for years and my wife got 1 virus in the past 5 years+ from a banner ad on a legit site.  But with partitions, file servers, and backups, it just wasn't a big problem.